# How to break out of a loop depending on a CheckBox Checked value while the loop is running?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Lets say I want to call a function repeatedly if the user selects a CheckBox named "repeat" but the calls to the function should stop as soon as the user 'unchecks' the CheckBox.

I tried using the 'Checked', 'Click' and 'Tap' event of the CheckBox but once the loop starts, it does not sense any changes in the checkbox's state.

I even tried using a loop inside another button's _Click method, but then that creates a lock on the Button's 'pressed' state.

Any ideas/alternate suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a loop, use a `Timer` and switch it on and off depending on the checkbox state.

```
    // your loop replacement: a timer
    Timer timer;

    // this method is called periodically by the timer - do whatever you want here
    // but make sure you use proper dispatching when accessing the UI (!)
    private void MyTimerCallback(object state)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Action!");
    }

    // this creates and starts the timer
    private void StartTimer()
    {
        // set the timer to call your function every 500ms
        timer = new Timer(MyTimerCallback, null, 500, 500);
    }

    // stop the timer
    private void StopTimer()
    {
        timer.Dispose();
    }

    // Checked handler for the checkbox: start the timer
    private void checkBox1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StartTimer();
    }

    // Unchecked handler for the checkbox: stop the timer
    private void checkBox1_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StopTimer();
    }
```

Some notes about the callback ("MyTimerCallback"):

> The method does not execute on the thread that created the timer; it
>   executes on a ThreadPool thread that is supplied by the system.
>   (Source: Documentation of `Timer`)

This is important and tells you to not access any UI elements directly from this method. Do something like this instead:

```
textBlock1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { textBlock1.Text = "Changed text"; });
```

Comment: Good. As a general rule of thumb: Don't create any busy loops in the main thread as they will block the user interface. Instead use some callback mechanism or thread-based alternative like the `Timer`.

Answer (score 0):

Spinning in a loop on the UI thread is bad practice. Why not bind to a dependency property instead and then do what you need in the `PropertyChangedCallback`?

XAML

```
<!-- MainWindowInstance is the x:Name of this class, you can avoid setting the -->
<!-- ElementName if you setup a DataContext -->
<CheckBox Content="Repeat" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=MainWindowInstance, Path=Checked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Code-behind

```
public bool Checked
{
   get { return (bool)GetValue(CheckedProperty); }
   set { SetValue(CheckedProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty CheckedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Checked", typeof(bool), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata((s, e) =>
{
   if ((bool)e.NewValue)
   {
      // Checked
      MessageBox.Show("checkbox checked");
   }
   else
   {
      // Unchecked
   }
}));
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit of a newbie here. How exactly do I use the OnPropertyChanged? Eg if I need to print a MessageBox saying "checkbox checked" each time the check box is checked and "unchecked" vice versa, how would I implement that?

Comment: In the XAML I'm binding the CheckBox.IsChecked property to the Checked property in the code-behind which is just a wrapper around the dependency property. See the DependencyProperty.Register() call. The PropertyMetadata constructor takes a callback where you can check the value of the property which my examples shows as well.

Comment: I tried exactly what you mentioned. I added the XAML, then the back end however while running, the CheckedProperty changed events don't take place for some reason. No message in the debug area. Maybe I'm still doing something wrong :(

Comment: I tested the code and it works. Perhaps you aren't using the ElementName properly. The whole point is to tell your check box where the property you are binding to lives. If you are using MVVM your DataContext is the view model and the path is simply the property name. If you're NOT using MVVM then you need to tell your check box that the property lives on the UserControl itself. I did it by setting the x:Name MainWindow to 'MainWindowInstance' and then referencing that in the ElementName of the binding.